# Compile a C# Portable Class Library using NAnt?

Tags: c#, .net, cruisecontrol.net, nant, portable-class-library

Can we compile portable class library using nant? It would be nice if nant could resolve the target framework/profile and also download nuget packages. Would be easy introduce new pcl libraries on an existing cruisecontrol.net build environment.

Comment: With MSBuild open source, there is little interest to have NAnt always up to date.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment.  You want your CC.NET to be a "fancy" called for: msbuild.exe mybuilddefinition.proj.